# Problema com setInterval()

Tags: php, javascript

Então pessoal..
Tenho um código que trás um setInterval das mensagens passadas entre os usuários `de` e `para` na função abaixo..

```
    function openWidChat(de,para) {
        var url_s = $("#url_s").val();
        $("label#boxC input").val('');
        $("label#boxC input").removeAttr('disabled');
        $("label#boxC input").attr('user-de',de);
        $("label#boxC input").attr('user-para',para);

        $("#mensChat div._5chat").fadeIn(400).html('<div class="maxWid_16"><img src="'+ url_s +'/themes/4space/images/load/loadLikesW.gif" alt="" width="16" height="16"></div>');
        para = setInterval(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: url_s +"/demo/chat/chat.php",
                data:'d='+de+'&p='+para+'&url_s='+url_s,
                type: "POST",
                cache: false,
                success : function(html){
                    $("#mensChat div._5chat").html(html);
                }
            });
        }, 1000);
    }
```

até então ele funciona de boa, mas quando clico em um nome de outro usuário para iniciar na mesma box uma nova conversa o `setInterval` fica indo e voltando em todos os usuários que eu cliquei para conversar... Fica um vai e vem do caramba..

Alguém tem uma solução pra isso?

Comment: Um problema, tens o parâmetro `para` e uma variável `para`. Isso dá problemas porque estás a fazer uso do `para` na chamada de Ajax. Além disso, convinha iniciar a variável `para` com `var para ...`. Sugiro que facultes nomes diferentes entre o parâmetro e a variável.

Answer (score 1):

Fala meu,

Olha só, você precisa colocar no seu programa uma estrutura que utilize o comando "clearInterval". O setInterval é um loop infinito, e só vai parar quando você pedir para ele parar, por exemplo:

```
var looper = setInterval(function(){},1000); //Loop de 1s

clearInterval( looper ); //Para o loop.
```

Você precisa associar a função à uma variável para manter o controle dela, que no seu caso é a variável "para". Em algum ponto do seu programa (como quando você muda de usuário) você vai precisar colocar o **clearInterval** dessa forma:

```
clearInteval( para );
```

Depois vai ser necessário reiniciar o loop.

[Tenho uma resposta aqui que pode te ajudar a criar uma estrutura de código.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/73561/setinterval-como-voltar-novamente-depois-de-dar-um-clearinterval/73642#73642)

Olhando seu código, te aconselho também a estudar um cara chamado **"websockets"**. É algo mais complexo, mas vai te ajudar a entender mais conceitos importantes como "pooling request", por exemplo, mas se encaixa nesse tipo de programa que você tem aí.

Espero ter ajudado! Abraços!