# setInterval como voltar novamente depois de dar um clearInterval?

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos

por questões de estudo e de conhecimento, como eu poderia limpar um setInterval e depois de acordo com algum evento eu poder continuar a sua execução novamente.

```
'use strict';

    var imgAtual = 0;
    var arrImg = ['images/relatorio.jpg', 'images/clp.jpg', 'images/estudo-viabilidade.jpg', 'images/padrao.jpg'];

    function mudarImagem(){
        var imgElm = document.querySelector('.img-slide');
        if(imgAtual < arrImg.length){
            imgElm.setAttribute('src',arrImg[imgAtual]);
            imgAtual++;
            console.log(imgAtual);
        }else{
            imgAtual = 0;
            imgElm.setAttribute('src',arrImg[imgAtual]);
            imgAtual++;
        }

        imgElm.addEventListener('click',function(){
            clearInterval(mudando);
        })

    }



    var mudando = setInterval(function(){
        mudarImagem();
    },1000);
```

Comment: @Marconi eu quero voltar com a execução do setInterval depois que eu já paralizei ela com um clearInterval.

Answer (score 1):

Fala meu,

Se eu compreendi certo sua pergunta, você quer algo como um "**pause()**" e de pois dar um "**play()**" novamente. Bem, para o setInterval isso não existe de forma nativa. Vai depender de você criar uma estrutura que possa lidar com isso.

Eu aconselho algo desse tipo:

```
var SimpleSlider = {
    loopTimer : null, //variável de controle para o setInterval

    loop: function(){ //função que faz o loop
        var me = this;  //referencia para o contexto do SimpleSlider 
        this.loopTimer = setInterval(function(){
           me.mudarImage();
        },3000); //Executa a transição a cada 3s
    },

    mudarImage : function(){
        console.log('Mudar imagem');
        //Aqui vem a lógica de transição de imagens
    },

    play : function(){
        this.mudarImage();
        this.loop(); 
    },
    pause : function(){
        clearInterval( this.loopTimer ); //"Pause". O clearInterval para tudo.
    }
};
```

Para usar, use um console como o F12 do IE ou o Developer Tools do Chrome, cole o código e faça:

```
SimpleSlider.play();  // espere as respostas
SimpleSlider.pause(); // as respostas vão parar de sair no console.
```

Essas funções podem estar em eventos de botões por exemplo.
Espero ter ajudado! 
Abraços!